# Modifying the Input file to required output file

Tags: python-3.x

I have an input file. I want to modify the input file as below:-

Input File:-

```
foo bar flower

dragon smile

friends few are there. Here it is

...

..

..

.

foo bar flower

beauty good

ugly bad

...

..

.
```

My Output Fie:-

```
foo bar flower

dragon smile

friends few are there. Here it is

...

..

..

.

//foo bar flower

//beauty good

//ugly bad

//...

//..

//.Rest of the file
```

I wanted to look back. But could not figureout.

From the last occurrence of `foo bar` till the EOF in the file, I need to prefix the outputs with '`//`'

Comment: Could you show what you have attempted, and where you are stuck? Reversing a list can be done with `reversed`.

Answer (score 0):

if the file is not too big, you can read it's lines into a list and then process it looking back and forward how many times you want.

here's an example, let me know if this works for you (notice you should replace `input.txt` with your real file name):

```py
content = []
with open('input.txt') as f:
    content = f.readlines()

# we find the last index by finding the first occurrence in the reversed list, then subtracting it from the list length
last_foobar_index = len(content) - 1 - content[::-1].index('foo bar flower\n')

# now we go over each line from that index and add leading "//"
for i in range(last_foobar_index,len(content)):
    content[i] = "//"+content[i]

# now just write it to an output file
with open('output.txt', 'w+') as f:
    f.writelines(content)
```

**EDIT - BECAUSE THE FILE IS INDEED BIG**

because the file might be too big to fit in memory, we want to iterate the file in a memory-efficient way, as described in [Methods of File Objects](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects).

we'll make 2 passes over the file, in the first one we'll just find the index of the latest `foo bar`, and in the second one we will create output.txt:

```py
latest_foobar_index = 0

with open('input.txt') as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
        if line.startswith('foo bar'):
            latest_foobar_index = i

    f.seek(0) # go back to the start of the file

    with open('output.txt', 'w+') as out:   
        for i, line in enumerate(f):
            if i >= latest_foobar_index:
                out.write('//')
            out.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks @Adam.Er8 for the response. The Input file is indeed big. I don't want to read the entire file into list.

Comment: OK, this will requires 2 passes over the file, I will edit my answer accordingly.